# Add text captions/subtitles to videos without Adobe Premiere? (burn in)

Tags: applications, video, video-editing

I want to add text captions to some videos I am uploading to social media/Facebook.

Is there a simple way to do this in QuickTime? Adobe Premiere is too expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Video Caption Maker](http://www.videocaptionmaker.com)** to add captions/subtitles directly to your videos. Its free (with a watermark).

Comment: ill give this a try, tnx